# SQL Server ISDATE() Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and need to verify that a certain column contains only dates.  I'm trying to count the number of records that are not follow a date format.  If I check a field that I did not define as type "date" then the query works.  However, when I check a field that I defined as a date it does not.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    count(case when ISDATE(Date_Field) = 0 then 1 end) as 'Date_Error'
FROM [table]
```

Column definition:

```
Date_Field(date, null)
```

Sample data: `'2010-06-27'`

Error Message:

> Argument data type date is invalid for argument 1 of isdate function.

Any insight as to why this query is not working for fields I defined as dates?

Thanks!

Comment: If you defined the column with the Date type, it ***IS*** a Date. Period. No need for further checks.

Comment: The isDate function expects a text field as an input, not a date field.  As Joel C said, if the field is defined as a date field, then the values in that field must be dates.

Comment: Also: it's bad to store date values in string columns in the first place. Needing to use ISDATE() for anything other than fixing old schema designs is a code smell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you defined the column with the Date type, it ***IS*** a Date. Period. This check is completely unnecessary.

What you may want to do is look for `NULL` values in the column:

```
SELECT SUM(case when Date_Field IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as 'Date_Error' FROM [table]
```

I also sense an additional misunderstanding about how Date fields, including DateTime and DateTime2, work in Sql Server. The values in these fields are not stored as a string in any format at all. They are stored in a binary/numeric format, and only shown as a string as a convenience in your query tool. And that's a good thing. If you want the date in a particular format, use the [`CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function in your query, or even better, let your client application handle the formatting.

Comment: @Kaf I like to be explicit

Answer (score 6):

`ISDATE()` only evaluates against a STRING-like parameter (varchar, nvarachar, char,...)

To be sure, `ISDATE()`'s parameter should come wrapped in a cast() function.

i.e.

```
Select isdate(cast(parameter as nvarchar))
```

should return either 1 or 0, even if it's a MULL value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

IsDate takes a character string or exression that yeilds a character string as it's argument

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this method ISDATE() only admits arguments of type datetime and smalldatetime within the "time" types, so it won´t work if you are using date type.

Also if you use date as type for that field, you won´t have to check the information there because it won´t admit other type of field.

You shoul only check for null values in your column, that´s all.